# asp.net MVC return View - add variable in viewpath

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have different different pages which i want to call from one controller action

here is what i've done

```
  public class TemplatesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Select(int id)
    {

        return View("Temp"+(id));


    }

}
```

i have different view pages like
Temp1,  Temp2, Temp3,..etc...
the id is fetched properly
but i think there is a problem in concatenation

i want final result to be

**return view("Temp1");**

in another case it would be

**return view("Temp2");**

so that these pages can be called without creating controllers for each of the pages.

pls help.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return View("Temp"+id.ToString());
```

The parameter is a String, so you can build the string up however you want.

```
string RetView = "Temp"+id.ToString();
return View(RetView);
```

> so that these pages can be called
>   without creating controllers for each
>   of the pages.

Although i'm not sure if this is good practice, I suppose it depends on how many views you have.